# Как после элемента брать еще 1

Tags: c#, парсер, htmlagilitypack, anglesharp

У меня есть элемент `<tr class="b-pr_t_hl">` после него идут обычные `tr` и дальше это повторяется несколько раз. Мне нужно вытягивать `<tr class="b-pr_t_hl">` и после него брать 1 tr и так пока не закончатся `<tr class="b-pr_t_hl">`
[image: gle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `XPath` есть такая вещь, как `following-sibling`, он позволяет взять следующую "ноду" после указанной. Также в `HtmlAgilityPack` есть у каждой ноды свойство `NextSibling`, которое по идее должно делать аналогичную вещь, но в кривом HTML он выдаст только мусор.

И так, предположим, что у нас есть такой кривой HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr class="b-pr_t_hl">Object 1</tr>
  <tr>Object 2</tr>
  <tr>Object 3</tr>
  <tr class="b-pr_t_hl">Object 4</tr>
  <tr>Object 5</tr>
</table>
```

Из него нам надо вытянуть значения `Object 1`, `Object 2`, `Object 4` ну и `Object 5`.

- Получаем все ноды `tr` с классом:

  ```
  var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='b-pr_t_hl']");
  ```
- Далее проходимся по полученной коллекции и берем следующую ноду после указанной, ну и выводим заодно:

  ```
  foreach (var node in nodes)
  {
      var nextNode = node.SelectSingleNode(".//following-sibling::tr");
      Console.WriteLine($"{node.InnerText} -- {nextNode.InnerText}");
  }
  ```

  Здесь стоит заметить, что стоит `.` - она означает, что поиск пойдет не по всему документу, а начиная с текущей ноды. Ну и `following-sibling::tr` - говорит, что нам нужен следующая нода с типом `tr`.

В итоге результатом будет:

```
Object 1 -- Object 2
Object 4 -- Object 5
```

Ну а дальше все зависит от задачи и того, что необходимо, к примеру почему бы не получить сразу объект, содержащий в себе только необходимые значения?

```
var result = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='b-pr_t_hl']")?
    .Select(x=> new { Text = x.InnerText, NextText = x.SelectSingleNode(".//following-sibling::tr")?.InnerText });

foreach (var item in result)
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Text} -- {item.NextText}");
```

Оставлю [шпаргалку по XPath](https://devhints.io/xpath), во многом думаю поможет. Удачи!