# Как из элемента i взять текст?

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Использую xpath, есть html, где из i элемента нужно взять текст, как это сделать?

---

### html:

[image: HTML]

---

### C# код сейчас:

```
node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='b - container']/div[1]/dl/dt/span/i");
            Cause.Text = "Причина:\n" + node[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: И что, этот код не работает? `b - container` пробелы уберите `b-container` должно быть. И с чего вы взяли, что этот текст, если вы про скриншот, находится внутри тега `i`? Внутри тега `i` текста нет вообще.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1130049/220553

Comment: @aepot а как же " экономические споры по гражданским правоотношениям "? И да, он не работает, вместо причины выводится пустота...

Comment: Содежимое тега находится между открывающим тегом `<i>` и закрывающим `</i>`. Все что за пределами - не относится к этой html ноде.

Comment: @aepot Так тоже не работает

 `node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='b - container']/div[1]/dl/dt/span/text()");


                        SetTextToControl(Cause, "Причина:\n" + node[0].InnerText.Trim());`

Comment: Пробелы забыли убрать, я выше вам рисал. Будьте внимательней.

Comment: @aepot все равно!

Comment: Из показанного фрагмента разметки больше ничего не понять. Ну и я не силен в XPath, предпочитаю CSS селекторы.

Comment: [ссылка] (https://kad.arbitr.ru/Card?number=%D0%9084-3532/2021)
Вот сайт, сверху написано "экономические споры по гражданским правоотношениям" вот этот текст из html нужно получить. Вот информация. Можете хотя бы показать способ с css???

Comment: С селекторами это нужно поставить еще один нугет пакет Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack, подключить его через `using` и написать `string text = doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelector(".b-container span").InnerText.Trim();`. Html посмотреть не смогу с телефона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

икспас:

`//*[@id="b-container"]/div[1]/dl/dt/span`

вероятнее всего твоя ошибка была в пробелах в айдишнике и лишней нодой в конце.